# Real size of an HTML "stretched" component

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, width

I'm having a problem with a table in which I fixed some sized for the cells and the cells does not react.

Actually I'm fixing "min-width", "max-width", "width" to the same value without having any result (but for the first column).

Actually I'm trying to get the REAL / post render size of the cell but I cannot get it. If I use method like:

- width
- .css("width")
- outerWidth

And so on, I received a "wrong result" that means that I receive 100 when the cell is stretched up to 200 (for instance).

Is there any way (via javascript or jQuery) to know the exact post render size?

I tried to add Margin and border to the width I received, but still is a complete different number.

Thank you

EDIT:

Actually I'm executing more than once the same bunch of code and the width "tend" to the exact value. Why is working like this? If I execute the code inside the "$(window).load" function, is the document already "done, fixed and stretched"?

Comment: did you try calculating the width after every DOM element is loaded?

Comment: jquery outerWidth() is pretty reliable, just make sure that you're checking the right <td> element.  It may be pulling the width of an earlier <td> because your identifier matches multiple cells - in that case, outerWidth() will simply return the width of the first matched element.

Comment: at otinanai: Yes, is called after the ready function and returns the wrong value
@Dave: I have, with outer width, the same problem, it returns me the "width" fixed on the element + padding. The problem is that (as render) the element doesn't care of the width and stretches as the page size.
document.getElementById("ID").offsetWidth; Seems to work good but not always..

Comment: So, it's calculating based on the specified width of the element, but the element is actually being stretched wider than that?

Maybe use min-width and max-width, but not width?

Comment: I'm using them but I have columns inside a table so even if I set the column to XX min-width and XX max-width the column will be stretched to fix the size of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AUFH2/) that you can play with.

JS

```
$('.showme1').append( $('.testdiv').width() );

$('.buttonclass').click(function(){
       $('.showme2').append( $('.testdiv').width() );
});
```